# How to check type of variable

Tags: java, types

I want check the variable type. How do I do that? For e.g

```
if (num is of String type )
    {This must be executed}
```

I'm currently using Java 17. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceof String` to check whether a variable is a String.

```java
if (num instanceof String) {
    // code to be executed
}
```

Comment: Ok It works Can I check the primitive data types in the same way ? by the way thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot for primitive data types but there are other ways to check if a value could be valid for that particular data type, e.g. `(x == (int) x)` for `int`, `String.valueOf(b).toLowerCase() == String.valueOf(true) || String.valueOf(b).toLowerCase() == String.valueOf(false)` for `boolean`.